# Integrate Data-table into Ionic 3 project

Tags: angular, ionic2, ionic3, angular-ui-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have created website using Ionic 3. I would like to create a data table like the one shown [here](http://datatables.net/examples/styling/bootstrap.html).

How can I integrate this library in on my website?
Is there anything specific to Ionic/Angular context I should do?

Answer (score 4):

You can simple use Angular component https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/welcome
Works on angular 2+ so it will work on Ionic 3.

Install using NPM:

```
npm install jquery --save
npm install datatables.net --save
npm install datatables.net-dt --save
npm install angular-datatables --save
npm install @types/jquery --save-dev
npm install @types/datatables.net --save-dev
```

Copy styles and scripts to /assets folder and add to index.html

```
<link href="assets/css/jquery.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="assets/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/jquery.dataTables.js></script>
```

Import dependency in app.module.ts

```
import { DataTablesModule } from 'angular-datatables';
```

Add to imports section:

```
  imports: [
    ...,
    DataTablesModule
  ],
```

Using component: add directive `datatable` to html tag:

```
<table datatable [dtOptions]="dtOptions">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>First name</th>
    <th>Last name</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr *ngFor="let person of persons">
    <td>{{ person.id }}</td>
    <td>{{ person.firstName }}</td>
    <td>{{ person.lastName }}</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```